# Intuition on transition rate matrix of Continuous Time Markov Chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

According to wiki this is the definition:
[def of transition rate matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39lCH.png)

That I do not get is why each row needs to sum up to 0, and why $q_{i,i}$ is negative $\lambda_i.$

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have a amount of matter on a vertex $V_i$.

The line $q_{i,j}$ indicate the variation of the matter which were on $V_i$ is going. As nothing is create and nothing disappear, the mass of matter is still the same after the operation. So the line sum up to $0$.

And because the vertex $V_i$ can only loose matter, $q_{i,i}$ is negative.